# Trouble simply inserting data in Sqlite3 table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have been trying familiarize myself with Sqlite3. I am using Python The most simple thing which is inserting data into my tables is not working for me. When I run, gives no errors yet when I check my database, it is still empty. I am surely missing something very simple.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('newtest.db')

c = conn.cursor()
def database_insert():
   c.execute('INSERT INTO products VALUES ("Oishi", 12, 3, 5, 4)')
   conn.commit()

database_insert()
```

Comment: Was the table `products` created? Change the code `res = c.execute('INSERT INTO products VALUES ("Oishi", 12, 3, 5, 4)')` and print `res`. What do you get?

Comment: Do  `print("affected rows = {}".format(c.rowcount))` as well

Comment: Hello! I had created the table before hand but yes it finally worked after I followed your recommendation; thank you very much. I'm not sure why my last one did not insert. Can I ask why my last code would not work?

Comment: Great.Glad to know.